# Entry processes - количества процессов за последние сутки

Tags: ajax

У меня небольшая самописная CRM. Все действия кнопок, загрузки страниц, таблиц, любой информации делаются с использованием запросов ajax на php сервер. некоторые запросы возвращают информацию в формате json некоторые в html, как в Open Cart. Также есть запросы по API на получение информации со стороннего сервера. Некоторые из них выполняются каждые 20-30 сек. Такие запросы на сторонний сервер также выполняются с помощью CRON один раз в минуту. Всё это работает на Бизнес хостинге Ukraine.

ПРОБЛЕМА: При загрузке большого отчета со стороннего сервера, время загрузки которого от 30 сек при низкой загрузке всего сервера, получаю повышение Entry processes. Ограничение хостинга 200. Если этот долгий отчет выгружается, когда в системе работает несколько человек, приводит к повышению Entry processes до ограничения 200 и ошибки 508. При проведении тестов, заметил, что до тех пор, пока ajax не вернет результат выполнения этого большого отчета, если я открываю в новой вкладке другую страницу этой CRM, то все действия на ней зависают, до завершения ajax на другой странице.

ВОПРОС: Честно гуглил, искал, но безуспешно. Объясните мне пожалуйста кто разбирается. Почему ajax запросы на одной странице, ждут завершения выполнения ajax запроса выполняющегося на другой вкладке. И как это работает в масштабе сервера. Т.к. у меня на этом же хостинге ещё 3 сайта, которые работают по этому же принципу и подключены к одной БД.

Comment: Проблема в серверной стороне. Очередь там синхронная, в отличие от JS и, например, в первой вкладке идёт долгая выборка из БД, а во второй пошёл запрос на другую выборку..... Так что второй будет ждать пока первый не выполнится

Comment: Как мне быть? Почему тогда на других сайтах я могу ждать загрузки таблицы и это не останавливает работу других пользователей и вкладок? Значит есть решение. В какую сторону мне смотреть, что искать для решения проблемы?

Comment: "Почему тогда на других сайтах я могу ждать загрузки таблицы и это не останавливает работу других пользователей и вкладок?" --- приведите, пожалуйста, примеры таких сайтов. Где идёт долгий запрос к серверу, вы открываете другую вкладку и там сразу всё работает. .............."В какую сторону мне смотреть, что искать для решения проблемы?" --- смотря на чём написана серверная часть. Если php - есть библиотеки асинхронного php. Например ReactPHP, woole, amphp и т.д. Можно писать сервер на NodeJs и Go

Comment: На счет примеров, Google Adwords наверное не корректно сравнивать, но учитывая, что даже на мощном ПК и высокой скоростью интернета, некоторые отчеты грузятся и по 20 сек. А пользователей там тысячи, одновременно делающих тоже самое. Есть другие сайты, которые я мог бы привести в пример, но без доступа в аккаунт это не имеет смысла.

Comment: В любом случае я благодарен за ответ, я самоучка и данная информация сломала мою картину мира в плане понимания как всё работает). Прошу ещё уточнить, серверная сторона - это мой код PHP или же сервер хостинга